# Textbox focusing second word

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have a problem in text box always focusing second word instead of first word. If I set Maxlenth=1 means it doesn't allow me to type. After pressing backspace only I can type.  Help me out from this.

Here is my Code:

```
<input type="text" name="exMark[]" id='exMark'   value=" " style="width:30px; height:20px; text-transform:uppercase;" maxlength='1'>
```

Answer (score 1):

remove space from attribut  **value=" "**. Change it to **value=""** or dont write it at all.

```
<input type="text" name="exMark[]" id='exMark'   value="" style="width:30px; height:20px; text-transform:uppercase;" maxlength='1'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove that extra space in `value=" "`